# Is it possible to create data with a specific slope and pearson correlation coefficient in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, correlation, lm

For example, I would like two variables, `x` and `y` to have a correlation coefficient of 0.7 and a slope of 1.5, with a specified mean and sample size for both variables. I don't care if the data is normal or not.

I messed around with `MASS` a lot, using `mvrnorm` to get a specific correlation coefficient, but I couldn't manipulate it to also give me the slope.

```
out <- mvrnorm(100, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1),ncol = 2), empirical = TRUE)
```

This gives me a correlation coefficient of 0.5, but it also gives me a slope of 0.5 when I plot the data.

```
cor(out)
plot(out)
cor(out[,1], out[,2])
fit <- lm(out[,2]~out[,1])
fit
# Call:
# lm(formula = out[, 2] ~ out[, 1])

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)     out[, 1]  
#  -8.604e-17    5.000e-01
```

Is there a program that can do what I want or anyway to get these requirement on point by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes of scale will not change the correlation coef:

```
> out2[,2] <- out[,2]*10

> cor(out2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.0  0.5
[2,]  0.5  1.0

plot(out2)

> lm(out2[,2]~out2[,1])

Call:
lm(formula = out2[, 2] ~ out2[, 1])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    out2[, 1]  
 -5.732e-16    5.000e+00
```

Comment: @MaxwellChandler - To expand on this, you can do: `out[, 1] <- out[, 1]*coef(fit)[2]/1.5` to achieve a slope of 1.5. Confirm with `lm(out[, 2] ~ out[, 1]); cor(out[, 1], out[, 2])`.